# Alembic detecting tables that already exits,so it trying to create them again

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

My model of animation table is below: In the database there are not the test column and I want to update it with alembic.

```
class Animation(Base):
    __tablename__="Animation"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True,autoincrement=True)
    name=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    description=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    animation=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    created_at=Column(DateTime)
    updated_at=Column(DateTime)
    test=Column(DateTime)
```

But alembic detecting all existing tables and trying to recreate them. So it returns an error when ı run the command that "alembic upgrade head".It says that the table already exists.

Version script like this when ı run the autogenerate command :

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Animation',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('animation', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('test', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_Animation_id'), 'Animation', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('Faq',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('animation_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_Faq_id'), 'Faq', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('Service',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('plate', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('arrive_city', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('arrive_district', sa.VARCHAR(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('departure_time', sa.Time(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_Service_id'), 'Service', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.drop_index('ix_Service_id', table_name='service')
    op.drop_table('service')
    op.drop_index('ix_Animation_id', table_name='animation')
    op.drop_table('animation')
    op.drop_index('ix_Faq_id', table_name='faq')
    op.drop_table('faq')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('faq',
    sa.Column('id', mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('animation_id', mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    mysql_collate='utf8_turkish_ci',
    mysql_default_charset='utf8',
    mysql_engine='MyISAM'
    )
    op.create_index('ix_Faq_id', 'faq', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('animation',
    sa.Column('id', mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('animation', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    mysql_collate='utf8_turkish_ci',
    mysql_default_charset='utf8',
    mysql_engine='MyISAM'
    )
    op.create_index('ix_Animation_id', 'animation', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('service',
    sa.Column('id', mysql.INTEGER(display_width=11), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('plate', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('arrive_city', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('arrive_district', mysql.VARCHAR(collation='utf8_turkish_ci', length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('departure_time', mysql.TIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', mysql.DATETIME(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    mysql_collate='utf8_turkish_ci',
    mysql_default_charset='utf8',
    mysql_engine='MyISAM'
    )
    op.create_index('ix_Service_id', 'service', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_Service_id'), table_name='Service')
    op.drop_table('Service')
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_Faq_id'), table_name='Faq')
    op.drop_table('Faq')
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_Animation_id'), table_name='Animation')
    op.drop_table('Animation')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I am new at alembic and I could not find any solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual problem is here:

```
class Animation(Base):
    __tablename__="Animation"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True,autoincrement=True)
    name=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    description=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    animation=Column(VARCHAR(100))
    created_at=Column(DateTime)
    updated_at=Column(DateTime)
    test=Column(DateTime)
```

The table name must start with a lowercase letter. Alembic tries to find a table that starts with Uppercase A. But in MySQL table names starts with a lowercase letter. So they don't match. So Alembic tries to recreate them. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have already created the tables in your database, and have only started using alembic now that you need to add a new column.  So alembic assumes that it needs to create all the tables.

To workaround this you could:

- remove old migration scripts
- back up your database (just a precaution)
- do `DELETE FROM alembic_version` in your database, if the table exists
- revert your code to before you added the new column
- generate a migration, note the reference (`abc123ef` or similar)
- do `alembic stamp <reference>`
- add the code for the new column
- generate and run an alembic migration as usual

`alembic stamp` sets the reference of the previous migration in the database, so alembic knows where to start from.   By generating an initial migration and `stamp`ing it we let alembic know that it only needs to run the migration for the new column.

You may be able to simply run `alembic stamp head` rather than generating and stamping the initial migration, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: So I have to repeat this for each changes of the tables?

Comment: Once you have stamped the initial migration, alembic will always update the `alembic_version` table with the reference of the most recent upgrade, so for future changes you should only need to generate the migration and then do `alembic upgrade head`.

Comment: After stamp and generated the "alembic revision --autogenerate" command, it creates a migration script like above.And I have the same issue.It returns an error like Animation table already exist.